# why is this jquery button click event not firing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events

I have this page, here's the code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#<%= btnCompare.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        alert("Hey");
       // return false;
    });

});
```

and the button is,

```
<asp:Button Text="Compare" ID="btnCompare" runat="server" OnClick="btnCompare_Click" />
```

but the alert is not showing up?

**EDIT :**
The generated html

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCompare').click(function() {
            alert("Hey");
           // return false;
        });
    });
```

and

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCompare" value="Compare" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCompare" style="color:White;background-color:#6086AC;border-color:White;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;" />
```

**EDIT 2**
Could it be because I have a master page for this file, which also has a `document.ready` handler, so at the page load the both are getting loaded?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil
Its a server side code, which checks for some list and other stuff, it is getting called though, in case you wanna know, if you like, I can post its code too..

Comment: jQuery = Javascript = Client side code.. We need to see the generated HTML

Comment: This looks like it should work...  I find weird situations sometimes where the <%= bla.ClientID %> doesn't get processed and goes to the client literally.  Check if that's happening to you, or that some other bit of js isn't having an error and stop your script running

Comment: [It works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/NzPd6/), have you included jQuery correctly? Can you show how you have included it?

Comment: @w4rumy
yes, it does indeed! I dont know why its not working here! :(

Comment: @Razort4x maybe you could show example code where your problem is reproducable? As shown on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzPd6/), using the given code from your question, it is working fine. What browser are you using and is Javascript enabled? Any errors in the Javascript console (you know how to open it?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would rather be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('#<%= btnCompare.ClientID %>').submit(function() {
    alert("Hey");
   // return false;
});

});
```

**EDIT**

Replace it

```
<asp:Button Text="Compare" ID="btnCompare" runat="server" OnClick="btnCompare_Click" />
```

with

```
<asp:Button Text="Compare" ID="btnCompare" runat="server" />
```

Comment: `<%= btnCompare.ClientID %>` is the definition on the server side, you have to take a look at the generated HTML code.

Comment: @AshirvadSingh
Did that too.. still nothing

Comment: i dono i checked it on my system it is firing alert

Comment: have you include jquery.js properly can you check console if any error coming

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler doesn't prevent postback on button click. To prevent posting form back use `OnClientClick` button property:

```
<asp:Button Text="Compare" ID="btnCompare" runat="server" OnClick="btnCompare_Click" OnClientClick="return foobar()" />

function foobar(){
    alert("Hey");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. However, the button was part of a popup control, that was embedded in an `UpdatePanel`. To fix it, I had to use the following in a script tag:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(prm_endRequest);

function prm_EndRequest() {
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // your code here
   });
}
```